# WCF netNamedPipeBinding performance

Tags: performance, wcf

I'm trying to validate WCF performance using netNamedPipeBinding as per this article. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb310550.aspx

I have a WCF service and client hosted in single application.

WCF Host defined as follows:
[ServiceBehavior(ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple, UseSynchronizationContext = false, InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single)]

The test call doing the perf test looks as follows:

```
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
        sw.Start();
        int zLoopCount = 1000;
        for (int i = 0; i < zLoopCount; i++)
        {
            int z = zClient.Test(1);
        };
        sw.Stop();
        double zRequestsPerSecond = (double)sw.ElapsedMilliseconds / (double)zLoopCount;

        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("Done Making {0} requests \r\n", zLoopCount));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} ms to make all requests \r\n", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds));
        Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0} ms per objects \r\n", zRequestsPerSecond));
```

728 ms to make all requests

0.728 ms per objects

I'm running on a fairly descent spec Intel Gen 3 i5 and this equates to well under 2000 txn's per second and well under the claimed 8000 txns per second.

Is there some perf. tweaks that I should be making to the out the box config. I don't have any Throttling configured.

Thanks
Warrick

Comment: Try in release configuration without debugging anebled/without VS.

Comment: Yup, big difference when doing that. Sorry, that was rather obvious ... can't believe I didn't try that.